# When does system generate global variable $user?

Tags: 7, users

I want to add some data to global variable `$user` when user login, so when does system generate `$user`, and which hook I should implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way is to make use of [`hook_user_load`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_load/7)

> Act on user objects when loaded from the database.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> **$users**: An array of user objects, indexed by uid.

Also see [UserController](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/class/UserController/7)

> Controller class for users.
>
> This extends the DrupalDefaultEntityController class, adding required
>   special handling for user objects.

Comment: `hook_user_load()` is not invoked for the global `$user`, as `user_load()` is not used for it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno the doc says **Act on user objects when loaded from the database.**

Comment: That is true when `user_load()` is used to load the user object, but the global `$user` is not loaded with that function. When the user object is loaded using `db_query()`, or `db_select()`, `hook_user_load()` is not invoked.

Answer (score 7):

Drupal initializes the global `$user` during bootstrap. Unfortunately, it doesn't invoke any hook, as modules are not yet loaded. (Loading the enabled modules is the last step of Drupal bootstrap.)

The following code is used in the Drupal session handler [_drupal_session_read()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!session.inc/function/_drupal_session_read/7).

```
  // Handle the case of first time visitors and clients that don't store
  // cookies (eg. web crawlers).
  $insecure_session_name = substr(session_name(), 1);
  if (!isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]) && !isset($_COOKIE[$insecure_session_name])) {
    $user = drupal_anonymous_user();
    return '';
  }

  // Otherwise, if the session is still active, we have a record of the
  // client's session in the database. If it's HTTPS then we are either have
  // a HTTPS session or we are about to log in so we check the sessions table
  // for an anonymous session with the non-HTTPS-only cookie.
  if ($is_https) {
    $user = db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.ssid = :ssid", array(':ssid' => $sid))->fetchObject();
    if (!$user) {
      if (isset($_COOKIE[$insecure_session_name])) {
        $user = db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = :sid AND s.uid = 0", array(
          ':sid' => $_COOKIE[$insecure_session_name],
        ))
        ->fetchObject();
      }
    }
  }
  else {
    $user = db_query("SELECT u.*, s.* FROM {users} u INNER JOIN {sessions} s ON u.uid = s.uid WHERE s.sid = :sid", array(':sid' => $sid))->fetchObject();
  }
```

To extend the global `$user`, you can implement `hook_boot()`, which is invoked when Drupal is still bootstrapping, or `hook_init()`, which is not invoked for cached pages. `hook_user_load()` is invoked when `user_load()` is called, but `user_load()` is not used for the global `$user`.

As side note, the global `$user` is not a complete user object. It contains the data saved in the "users" table, and not (for example) the value of any field (fields implemented from the field API) associated to the user entity.
`$user->data` can be used to store extra data for the user object. Its content can be altered through `hook_user_presave()` in the same way done by [overlay_user_presave()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!overlay!overlay.module/function/overlay_user_presave/7).

```
function overlay_user_presave(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  if (isset($edit['overlay'])) {
    $edit['data']['overlay'] = $edit['overlay'];
  }
}
```

Comment: `$user->data` is a neat approach to store additional info, but `hook_user_load` can also be used to modify `$user` variable right ?

Comment: It can be used to alter `$user`, as long as it doesn't alter any property loaded from the {users} table: "Due to the static cache in `user_load_multiple()` you should not use this hook to modify the user properties returned by the {users} table itself since this may result in unreliable results when loading from cache."

Comment: By modify I meant adding additional info, sorry I wasnt clear before. Suppose I want to add nickname which is stored in another table I can still use `hook_user_load()` to add it right ?

Comment: Yes, you can. For `$GLOBALS['user']`, that value would not be loaded, except when the user logs in with the login form/lock. Once the session is active, that value will not be added to the user object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some data to `$user` just after login, you need to implement [hook_user_login](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) in your module as

```
function ModuleName_user_login(&$edit, $account) {
  //add your code here
}
```

Comment: Once users are logged in, they are kept logged in until the session is not expired; this means `hook_user_login()` is not invoked until the session doesn't expire. If a user visits a Drupal site every day, the session could not expire at all.